# Ubuntu 12.04 // Likewise Open // Unable to ever authenticate AD users

Tags: 12.04, networking, likewise

So Ubuntu 12.04, Likewise latest from the beyondtrust website.

- Joins domain fine.
- Gets proper information from `lw-get-status`.
- Can use `lw-find-user-by-name` to retrieve/locate users.
- Can use `lw-enum-users` to get all users.

Attempting to login with an AD user via SSH generates the following errors in the `auth.log` file:

```
Nov 28 19:15:45 hostname sshd[2745]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_winbind.so): /lib/security/pam_winbind.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 28 19:15:45 hostname sshd[2745]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_winbind.so
Nov 28 19:15:51 hostname sshd[2745]: error: PAM: Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info for DOMAIN\\user.name from remote.hostname
Nov 28 19:16:06 hostname sshd[2745]: Connection closed by 10.1.1.84 [preauth]
```

Attempting to login via the LightDM itself generates similar errors in the `auth.log` file.

```
Nov 28 19:19:29 hostname lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_winbind.so): /lib/security/pam_winbind.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 28 19:19:29 hostname lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_winbind.so
Nov 28 19:19:47 hostname lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "DOMAIN\user.name"
Nov 28 19:19:52 hostname lightdm: [lsass-pam] [module:pam_lsass]pam_sm_authenticate error [login:DOMAIN\user.name][error code:40022]
Nov 28 19:19:54 hostname lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_winbind.so): /lib/security/pam_winbind.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 28 19:19:54 hostname lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_winbind.so
```

Attempting to login via a console on the system itself generates slightly different errors:

```
Nov 28 19:31:09 hostname login[997]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_winbind.so): /lib/security/pam_winbind.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 28 19:31:09 hostname login[997]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_winbind.so
Nov 28 19:31:11 hostname login[997]: [lsass-pam] [module:pam_lsass]pam_sm_authenticate error [login:DOMAIN\user.name][error code:40022]
Nov 28 19:31:14 hostname login[997]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/tty2' FOR 'DOMAIN\user.name', Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info
Nov 28 19:31:31 hostname login[997]: FAILED LOGIN (2) on '/dev/tty2' FOR 'DOMAIN\user.name', Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info
```

I am baffled.  The errors obviously are correct, the file `/lib/security/pam_winbind.so` does not exist.  If its a dependancy/required, surely it should be part of the package?  I've installed/reinstalled, I've used the downloaded package from the beyondtrust website, i've used the repository, nothing seems to work, every method of installing this application generates the same errors for me.

---

UPDATE : 
Hrmm, I thought likewise didn't use native winbind but its own modules.

Installing `winbind` from apt-get uninstalls `pbis-open` (likewise) and generates failures when installing if `pbis-open` is installed first.

Uninstalled `winbind`, reinstalled `pbis-open`, same issue as above.  The file `pam_winbind.so` does not exist in that location.

```
Setting up pbis-open-legacy (7.0.1.918) ...
Installing Packages was successful

This computer is joined to DOMAIN.LOCAL

New libraries and configurations have been installed for PAM and NSS.
```

Clearly it thinks it has installed it, but it hasn't. It may be a legacy issue with the previous attempt to configure domain integration manually with winbind.

Does anyone have a working likewise-open installation and does the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` include references to winbind?

Or do the `/etc/pam.d/common-account` or `/etc/pam.d/common-password` reference `pam_winbind.so`?  I'm unsure if those entries are just legacy or setup by likewise.

UPDATE 2 :

Complete reinstall of OS fixed it and it worked seamlessly, like it was meant to and those 2 PAM files did NOT include entries for pam_winbind.so, so that was the underlying problem.

Thanks for the assist.

Comment: likewise and winbind are not suggested to exist at the same time, you will see a lot of weird issues ongoing. /etc/nsswitch.conf is configured how nss lookup information for passwd, group, dns, etc. /etc/pam.d/common-* are used for PAM authentication. if you have a clean installation for likewise and rely on it. pam_winbind.so shouldn't appear in /etc/pam.d/common-*

Comment: there's a 'pam-auth-update' command used to manage how individual application updates the PAM configuration. for winbind, it's the libpam-winbind:amd64.postinst file doing this job. just 'grep pam-auth-update' inside /var/lib/dpkg/info, you will know how it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

I see the post is old, but maybe it's worth to answer for others..

Likewise doesn't work with winbind (they refresh their krb5 ticket), you have to choose only one of them :/

after installing pbis you have to run

- domainjoin-cli to join the AD
- pam-auth-update to update PAM config

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have everything installed that you need.

In each of your errors I see this error.
PAM unable to dlopen(pam_winbind.so):/lib/security/pam_winbind.so: cannot open shared object No such file or directory

This is part of winbind.
http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/pam_winbind.8.html

Since I'm not sure how you installed your system I'm assuming you need to look there first.

Remember that Likewise uses the underlying protocols and tools like Samba in authentication. In a nut shell Winbind talks to Likewise which in turn talks to AD and when AD sends information back Likewise takes that and passes to Winbind, or other services.

hope that helps.

Comment: Hrmm, I thought likewise didn't use winbind.